# Node request not saving zip stream

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, node-request

In node-webkit I'm trying to download a remote file and save it to the same folder as the node executable (Windows)

```
request({
    url: updateUrl,
    encoding: 'binary',
    method: "HEAD"
}, function(err, headRes) {

    appUpdater.updateSize = headRes.headers['content-length'];

    console.log('Update size', appUpdater.updateSize);

    request
        .get({
            url: updateUrl,
            encoding: 'binary'
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error downloading update', err);
        })
        .on('data', function(data) {
            appUpdater.downloadedSize = appUpdater.downloadedSize + data.length;

            console.log(appUpdater.updateSize - appUpdater.downloadedSize);

        })
        .on('close', function(data) {
            console.log('Finished downloading update');
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('update.zip'));
});
```

The download progress in the console log looks absolute fine, it gets all the way to 0. However no file is ever created and the close event is never fired.

Comment: File paths are relative to the current working directory, which may not be where the script file is located. Check [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) or [`require('path').resolve('update.zip')`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_from_to) to see where it likely going. To define a path relative to the script file, you should combine it with [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) -- `path.join(__dirname, 'update.zip')`.

Comment: Regarding the [`'close'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close), it's documented that "*Not all streams will emit this.*" You may want to try the [`'end'` event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) instead.

Comment: Ahh you are correct, process.cwd() reports it running from local app data!

Comment: The final solution for me was var path = require('path');
var execPath = path.dirname( process.execPath ); do want to create an answer I can tick?